# Not enough data in Product\CollectionFactory, how can I get the rest?

Tags: magento2, products

I need to get several info from each single product in the catalog, so I used the `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` to get a collection of products.

Iterating through them I notice I cannot get all the data related to each product.

E.g.

- `$product->getData('name')` returns the Product Tile
- `$product->getData('qty')` dosen't work
- `$product->getData('quantity_and_stock_status')` returns 1 (just the number like a string)

In the last example `$product->getData('quantity_and_stock_status')`, if I load the product with `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`, then instead of returning 1, I get an array with 2 values `qty` and `is_in_stock`, which is what I want.

Just a quick note, loading each product with `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` is taking ages, so I'd avoid it.

Is it possible having all the info related to the product with the `Product\CollectionFactory`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some additional select attribute for that. Check magento default how they add. For example:

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/AbstractProduct.php**

```
/**
 * Add all attributes and apply pricing logic to products collection
 * to get correct values in different products lists.
 * E.g. crosssells, upsells, new products, recently viewed
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
 */
protected function _addProductAttributesAndPrices(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
) {
    return $collection
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
        ->addUrlRewrite();
}
```